# AOP AfterReturning function returns twice

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have a little problem. I'm calling `AfterReturning` function after some function returns and my `AfterReturning` function's working twice and I don't want that. Here is the code:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Configuration
public class AspectOP {

    LogController logcontroller = new LogController();

    @AfterReturning("execution(* com..*save*(..))")
    public void doSomething() {
        logcontroller.guestbook("XD");
    }
}
```

I have 2 save function and we changed names but it's same again. I've tried remove @Component or @Aspect then it's not working.

**EDIT**

My save function

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EntryController {

    @Autowired
    EntryRepository repo;
    Account account;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/getir", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Entries> getir(){
        return repo.findAll();

    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/saveentry", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Entries save(@RequestBody Entries entry) {
        return repo.save(entry);
    }
}
```

**LogController.class**

```
@Controller
public class LogController {

    @MessageMapping("/guestbook")
    @SendTo("/topic/entries")
    public Log guestbook(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
        return new Log(message);
    }
}
```

My main objective is when something is saved, I send something to my socket. It's working but doSomething functions is working twice.

Comment: can also show the class that you expect the advice to apply to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems advice applied to your EntryRepository class as well. change your pointcut expression to something like, to be only applied to EntryController's save method

```
@AfterReturning("execution(* com.xyz.EntryController.save*(..))")
```

Examples [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-examples)

Comment: but I want this function run in any class that functions's name has 'save' word in it.

Comment: @Gürsel hence, it is happening as it is expected(with your pointcut), advice will be applied twice when you invoke EntryController.save,
1. EntryController.save(..)
2. EntryRepository.save(..) - since it is invoked inside EntryController.save

Comment: EnrtyRepository is emty. It doesn't has any function.

Comment: if EntryRepository  is 'spring data repository interface' in runtime spring wires an implementation at runtime.

Comment: then what can we do?

Comment: I can think of 2 options

1. you want to provide customSave() method by extending spring data crud repository https://dzone.com/articles/customizing-spring-data-jpa
2. or change the method name of your EntryController.save to some other method name and change the point cut expression accordingly